# Intersection of infinite sets for $A_n = \{(n+1)k: k \in N\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on some basic set theory problems. However, for one of them, I am completely stumped. It states: $$A_n = \{(n+1)k: k \in N\}$$

Find $$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$$.

As per my understanding, $A_1$ $\bigcap$ $A_2$ would be all of the common multiples of 2 and 3, which is 6. Then, $A_1$ $\bigcap$ $A_2$ $\bigcap$ $A_3$ should be all of the common multiples of 2, 3, and 4, which is 12. So then $A_1$ $\bigcap$ $A_2$ ... $\bigcap$ $A_n$ would be all multiples of $n!$? Am I mistaken? It seems that all of the solutions online state that it would be $\emptyset$, but I am not sure how they are arriving at this solution. Where am I going wrong?

I really appreciate any and all help regarding this.

Comment: I have no idea why the indexing is off by one like that, but $A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_n$ is the set of all multiples of $\text{lcm}(2, 3, \dots n+1)$, not the factorial (it already isn't the factorial when $n = 3$ as you've seen).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, so the lcm(2,3,...,n+1) would be 2*3*...(n+1), which is effectively (n+1)!, no?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "effectively"; they're not the same sequence at all, and the lcm grows more slowly. You can see more at http://oeis.org/A003418.

Comment: Kandinskij has already answered that question, twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by contradiction there was a natural number $m$ belonging to that intersection, then it would be divisible by any prime number. This is a contradiction, since every number has a finite lenght factorization.

Comment: More simply, it would be divisible by $m+1$, which is absurd by size.